# Fetching email ID's of only the emails in the main Gmail Inbox

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API to fetch the email ID's like so:

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{myEmailID}/messages`

Once I have the email ID's, I then fetch the full emails like so:

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/\(id)?format=full`

However, what I'm noticing is that this will not only fetch the emails in my inbox, but also ones that I've archived. How do I configure this to only fetch the the emails that are in the current inbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetching all the emails with [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) you can filter them so you will only get the emails that are on the INBOX.

Using the parameter `labelIds`:

[image]

So a call would be like:

`https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?labelIds=INBOX&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

You can test the filters on the **Try this API** section of the [API method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)